# C# Storing class instances in an array to use in other forms

Tags: c#, arrays, list, class, instances

So i have my own class and i want to store an instance of the class by button click into a class array and then use this array in a different form under the same project however despite declaring it as public static i still can't access it on my other form. I have even tried putting it into the class itself just to see if that would work. I have heard you can use a list array but i am not sure how i would do that and again how to access it over my whole project.

Sorry if i missed something obvious or anything I'm fairly new to C#.

Comment: You should show your code so that it will be easier to identify what's wrong

Comment: Have you referenced project a from project b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you create the object in `Form1` and want to use it in `Form2`. You can do it like this:

```
// Form1-----------------------------------------------------

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string myName { get; set; }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass() {Name = "John"};
        myName = myClass.Name;
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// Form2-----------------------------------------------------

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        this.label1.Text = form1.myName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, this allowed me to do what i wanted :)